# validate a vuetify form using composition api with typescript

Tags: typescript, vuetify.js

I am trying to validate a form when it is submitted, but having trouble converting examples I have found to use the compostion api and typescript.
With the options api it appears that the correct syntax is something like

```
if (this.$refs.loginForm.validate()) {....}
```

and with the compostion api, other posts suggest

```
if (loginForm.value.validate()) {....}
```

but this is giving me a TS warning that the value is possibly null, and (more importantly) the `if()`  condition always succeeds, even if the form is submitted empty.

My full code is below. The `valid` variable appears to make no difference, so clearly something else is wrong with the methods I have used.:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'

const loginDialog = ref(false)

const userOrEmail = ref('');
const password = ref('');
const showPass = ref(false);
const loginForm = ref(null);
var valid = true;

const nameRules =   [  (value: string) => !!value || 'Required.', ];
const pwRules =     [  (value: string) => !!value || 'Required.', ];

function submit() {

   if (loginForm.value?.validate()) 
   {
        alert("submitted");
        loginDialog.value = false;
    }
}
</script>

<template>
  <v-dialog v-model="loginDialog" activator="parent" width="300">
  <v-card>
    <v-card-title class="headline black" primary-title>
      Sign in 
    </v-card-title>
    <v-card-text class="pa-5">
      <v-form @submit.prevent="submit" ref="loginForm"  v-model="valid" >
        <v-text-field v-model="userOrEmail"  :rules="nameRules"  label="User name or email" hint="Username will be 3 to 10 characters">
        </v-text-field>
        <v-text-field v-model="password" :append-inner-icon="showPass ? 'mdi-eye' : 'mdi-eye-off'"
          @click:append-inner="showPass = !showPass"   :type="showPass ? 'text' : 'password'" 
          hint="password will be at least 6 characters"
          :rules="pwRules"  label="Password">
        </v-text-field>
        <v-btn color="blue" type="submit" block class="mt-2">    Sign in     </v-btn>
       
      </v-form>
    </v-card-text>
  </v-card>
</v-dialog>
</template>
```

I have tried uploading a sample to the [Vuetify playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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) but it won;t run, getting errors I don't understand

Comment: Could you add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Have now tried but Vuetify playground giving errors I don't understand - see edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `validate()` on a VForm returns a promise, so you need to wait until it resolves:

```js
async function submit() {
  const {valid, errors} = await loginForm.value?.validate()
  if (valid) {
    ...
```

[playground example](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

---

Note that when `VForm` receives a submit event from the underlying `<form>` element, it triggers the same validation function you call through the template ref. Then it merges the returned promise with the submit event into a [SubmitEventPromise](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/f03038b48f68b1130b43101edfdfdf44aaa5aa39/packages/vuetify/src/composables/form.ts#L48-L48) and emits it to the [`@submit`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-form/#events-submit) (see [code](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/3eec1c134b1d61d468cf609967202c1ae6f8bddc/packages/vuetify/src/components/VForm/VForm.tsx#L41-L60)). So you are actually calling validate a second time (and could do without the template ref):

```js
async function submit(submitEventPromise: SubmitEventPromise) {
  const {valid, errors} = await submitEventPromise
  if (valid) {
    ...
```

[playground example](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNqlVt9v2zYQ/lcuwgCnQCQly7YHIckyYHle0WJPcYHS0tnmQpEcSckzXP3vO1I/TFtp0aBvJu+777s73p38fEj+0DprG0yK5M5hrQVz+LCUAHdtWnEm1AbatFYVivtlQicu/wy3ywRY6XjLnDJk0cygdHS545Xb0sXt9fUyCURENRITlRXKFbHnQRulbTeBg/LKScKuuKw8tweQXWmUEEK4ywNkpM9PAg8EJTNVTOjPqeNOIJSCWUu0W2SV4BJhJVj5QqFrw2tm9j1scgb4yDcSuJzYSPxINxfB/9ykoVn6a5RZQK2VqeHRNquau0wbbKlwBO0vTsAB7vnSNUdRxQaIXqWxaP4yTzXjYpmcggrTCPSBSFbjB//7HCHYKpD8TSTgUaAM4GtcWx7i9MCA23EhYIVwC07BzTWUW2boYdGcaZwmRMU7ZvT2XDXVdadMNUuUaeqOKuVSokl5qaQv6Vbt3pMD/A6LuuIp7nEBxfQ7Vev14pzosRS8fDmhi5nu4WL8PQvB7TWeqfqEguQY90xvqOpon6rKHAhk1sFvXy1s9Lx6983H9eHMq/aGh/HzWCoRBnYlGqRpGbMd2pamSJUvU+PXLv2ZenmcnUB/nNhR0I/CcYCmuaIwXh2r2JsG5+FwIDX3ZIwytuvucn/3Lbbxrt9vdOgXHB1PVggdbWm4dmDRNZqqKDeUkvM7yHvyWivj4PAxpP7k5/e9UTW32MGafsCC9qnj6/0iRoPBNUSAYKQ+pSeO1io1GOEunWnwnY9khEQzPkAWCwKM5ql9XrFFvettayas557EpxIOgBPdaW+Q8fmyZfT2BVhnuNy8g/sHuLgId/DlCyw+4L8NN1hli09RZH1nvtU9Cj9UmfyZ3csSLvtzXPUC5i8R2A/9s/c8B1Li1RVg3y6ecMeIeM7Xex3rkvUx3g+uvZkJNO7yM32bvAsws2lqoqAKWiVarPxS/KnX7D6Hcne+zfrGojZKrpK+M9Ka6ewfqyR9gUPAy8FA7VaMKSwT6hh/ps+Wc9oWeV5WktxoK/LWZBJdLnWdPxIsN410vMa0UvXjbXab/ZJX3Lr4OkNbpyujdtRVRLJMriIZ37nfITUgg8LNTS8x3KW0d6zXmHHnJNjSgqY/CxUaNN+b0plbnNaZaZbaUPqOCk5f+xd7VuvSL/ICnscgfyznwOapqIW7pLtKQqAk3Xskn/4HumIJRg==)

---

Finally, VForm has a [`:modelValue`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-form/#props-model-value) prop that indicates if the form is valid. In contrast to the `validate()` function, it is set through a watcher on the registered form inputs, which updates when all inputs have been validated (see [code](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/3eec1c134b1d61d468cf609967202c1ae6f8bddc/packages/vuetify/src/composables/form.ts#L136-L139)).

So unless validation on all inputs has been triggered manually, the `@update:modelValue` event will arrive only after `validation()` has finished, which by itself makes it an insufficient replacement for the SubmitEventPromise argument in the `@submit` handler. If you want to rely on `:modelValue` in the `@submit` handler without waiting for the promise, make sure that `validate()` has completed at least once, for example by triggering it manually when the form has loaded.

[playground example](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Comment: Thanks, I tried the async version but no change. And I cannot find an example of `modelValue` anywhere, to see how it should be used. I also tried uploading code to the vuetify playground (see my edit) but that is giving a whole load of confusing errors

Comment: First off, thank you for creating the playground! No kidding, most people fail before even trying. It is appreciated. The issue was that you were using typescript but hadn't declared it in the `<script>` tag, and the dialog was hidden and there was no way to show it. No biggie. I have added an updated version to the answer, I hope it shows how `validate()` and `:modelValue` works - you were right btw, in my initial answer, I had missed that `validate()` returns an object, not just a boolean. Let me know if this works for you now

Comment: Working great, thanks. Initially I was a bit confused, having both methods the solution looked overcomplicated! But I have now settled on using `validate()`. Still a TS error with `loginForm.value?.validate()` (_'validate' does not exist on type 'never'_) which I can't resolve, but that's a different question and it doesn't stop the code working :)

Comment: @MoritzRingler I think with `:modelValue`, validation errors using `:rules` attribute are not displaying in the fields.

Comment: @RohìtJíndal `:rules` on field level should be displayed independently of global validation, I think it is the other way round - `:modelValue` will not update until you have triggered validation on every field, either by changing them manually or calling global validation. Have a look at the updated answer.