# Form validate() method is not working with Vue 3 and Vuetify 3

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

**Problem Statement :** I just migrated my Vue 2 application (Contains Vuetify 2) into Vue 3 (with Vuetify 3). After migrating, validate() method on form is not working as expected. It always return truthy value if still there are errors in the form fields.

`(this.$refs.myForm as any & { validate: () => boolean }).validate()`

OR

`(this.$refs.myForm as any).validate()`

Above line of code always returns promise (Assuming a truthy value).

Here is the [`link`](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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) of Vuetify playground (Vue: 3.3.4 and Vuetify: 3.3.7)

**What I tried so far ?**

I tried to find the root cause of the issue and come up with the conclusion that `this.$refs.myForm.validate()` returns a promise (I think compiler assumes that as a truthy value).

I think I can achieve this by adding the `v-model` attribute in the form element and then on submit, I can check the form `v-model` value. Is this approach correct ? Or I have to change something in the original approach to make it work ?

Here is the playground [`link`](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNqNVE1v4jAQ/SuWL4BEknZbaaUIWPbS4x52jw0Hk0yKt/7I2k62qMp/79gEk0IlQEKxZ8bvvZkX5/md/myatGuB5nThQDaCOVgVipBFl9TaSNIlUlcglgXtmOBVQUM25EutHOMKzBAKQaP/x+1QJQj+LSLcfysokRWuHiNOrHPw5pKag6jGCTISUHNjnWISCvq5JDetAE/gk7/9+qKi1K1yYLyIu/OkYNuA/+TxyVcEBv613MAnZatFNhY9bhoT2PFpKrgfjwWb3TpF3L4BZLXtVnKHg8Ej2gtsDJfM7DGyLgUvX2PNE/qBc/sTNh4UUY5uBMqxHT7iDcTNIhs5i1tbGt64UAVvjTaOVFCzVjjyfkCrmGM5mc7IckWmQwyN8P7npGbCwvwYjJ7kZDKJ0ehDTp5Pc0GAFjxmhPQ/XpNpyMxwzK41OBjTghc6nn9ITH4hLuE2+pFOTlV9ZL/K9CMVoF7cjiyW5P7uVl7Z4tuxBYJtWeJ2TOFZUu6YYSW+WfZrLZth1c+GhQS30xUOJko7mYsTHwlGP60WkAr9MnU7btNgwOxYcOQ4PHtv82AsnVPB1atN/1qt8GIHzIKWFq9FNKSgO+cam2dZWSmsxCvGO5MqcJlqZIafBMfr/fohfUi/ZxW37hhK8LrYNIB5pE2heiTk0r9IiWTNGeshEZiH3vBLgnPG/RUJayzLDF5bLiGptAxaHg9aRuEUrEy2eL8sGAQp6DCXQOMF30B1rVukuIDOkK8DkxhQFRgwt3Z0dmzc1VnqorPB6J72cxqO4eCDZLr5AIakyNw=) as per this approach.

If I am using both the solutions together, It is working as per the expectation (Showing validation errors and preventing the submit if form has any error).

**Template :**

```
<v-form ref="myForm" v-model="valid">
```

**Script :**

On submit button `@click` event

```
if ((this.$refs.myForm as any & { validate: () => boolean }).validate() && this.valid) {
  ...
}
```

Above solution works fine but Still thinking about best approach. If I will use validate using VForm `v-model`, It is only preventing the submit if there is any errors but not highlighting the errors.

***Update :***

I implemented the solution suggested by [`Neha`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11834856/neha-soni) and it is working fine as per the requirement. The only thing which I noticed is that If I am assigning validation rules on a button click event method, validation not trigger for the first field on first click but working fine on another click. Here is the Vuetify [`playground`](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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) of the issue.

To get rid from this issue, I am using `nextTick` utitlity of `vue` and now it is validating all the fields at first click itself. Here is the working [`playground`](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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). Any input/suggestion on this ?

Comment: it's due to vuetify 3's new design to move closer to Material UI to support Promise rules I recommend using `await` instead of trying to catch synchronous events or you may prefer `@submit.prevent`

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76842428/4883195) is helpful

Comment: I am using nextTick() and inside that performing this validation.

Comment: @MoritzRingler I added the update in the question. Can you please have a look and provide your input ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Vuetify 3, the `validate` method returns the promise which can get resolved either using `await` or chaining the response using `.then()`. An example in documentation also demonstrates that [see here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/forms/#exposed-properties).

So, one approach for this problem could be using a `ref` variable on the form and on submit, simply call the `validate()` method and chain its response to extract the `valid` param which tells the validation status.

I used script `setup` in the demo. Here is the possible solution-

```
<template>
  <v-form ref="myForm">
    <v-container>
      <v-row>
        <v-col cols="12" md="4">
          <v-text-field
            v-model="firstname"
            :rules="nameRules"
            :counter="10"
            label="First name"
            required
          ></v-text-field>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      <v-btn type="submit" color="primary" @click="submitForm">Submit</v-btn>
    </v-container>
  </v-form>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
  import { ref } from 'vue'
  const myForm = ref();
  const firstname = ref(null);
  const nameRules = [
    value => {
      if (value) return true
      return 'Name is required.'
    },
    value => {
      if (value?.length <= 10) return true
      return 'Name must be less than 10 characters.'
    },
  ]
  const submitForm = () => {
    myForm.value?.validate().then(({valid: isValid}) => {
      console.log(isValid);
    })
  }
</script>
```

Here is the [working demo.](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for looking into the issue. Your solution works fine for me. I just added the update on the question after implemented your solution. Can you please have a look and provide your input/suggestion.

Comment: In the example code you provided, you're creating and assigning the rules array inside the submitForm function. This means that every time you click the "Submit" button, you're resetting the rules for both fields to the same array. The reactive behavior of Vue might not properly reevaluate these rules for each field at that time. So, it's better to put the rules outside of the function and it will work.

Comment: and that's the reason it is working with nextTick because you are telling Vue to wait until it's current cycle (resetting rules) finishes and then validate. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, I am pretty sure your solution does not work the first time, as the `@click` handler on the submit button will run before the submit event is triggered on the VForm or any other global validation could finish. So that means on the first click, when you do:

```
if ((this.$refs.myForm as any & { validate: () => boolean }).validate() && this.valid) {
  ...
}
```

- the `this.$refs.myForm.validate()` will always be true, since `validate()` returns a promise, and `Boolean(new Promise())` is true
- `this.valid` will be updated through the `v-model` after `validate()` has finished or when validation on every input has been triggered manually (this is [how it is implemented](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/next/packages/vuetify/src/composables/form.ts#L136-L139))

On subsequent clicks, `validate()` will have run at least once, so `:modelValue` will reflect the current validation status. So at that point, it works.

Using `nextTick` as you suggest will make execution wait, but for a more or less unrelated event. Waiting for the promise from validation() is the more direct and reliable approach and makes more sense semantically, so I would suggest to use that.

---

So I think the best solution is the one suggested by Vuetify, where you await the promise passed to the `@submit` handler (which is also more robust than using `@click` on the submit button, as it covers programmatic submits too):

```
async function submit(submitEventPromise: SubmitEventPromise) {
  const {valid, errors} = await submitEventPromise
  if (valid) {
    ...
```

([SubmitEventPromise](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/f03038b48f68b1130b43101edfdfdf44aaa5aa39/packages/vuetify/src/composables/form.ts#L48-L48) is the typescript type, it is exported by Vuetify)

Comment: I am getting this error `Cannot find name 'SubmitEventPromise'`. Shall I import this from any `vue` package ? FYI, I am using Vue 3 options API.

Comment: Also I added a `update` section in my post. If possible, I would love to hear your suggestion as well on that behavior.

Comment: Ah, the type is exported by Vuetify, I have added a link to the answer. In your playground, you set the rules in the submit handler, but Vue will perform the update after the validation, so during first validation, rules will be empty. Just create the ref with the rules instead of an empty array.

Comment: As I having some limitation (Invoking some utility methods to get the validations on some specific fields), I can not put the rules at the time of declaration. That's the reason I am putting those on submit event method.

Comment: Well, than you have to wait for `nextTick` and be aware that validation on individual components will not work until submit has been triggered.

Comment: Note that when waiting for the rules to update, `nextTick` is the correct event, as you wait for component bindings to update. Validation happens independently of that and might finish after `nextTick`, as, for example, it could include receiving data from a server. Using `nextTick` there is fragile.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! It helps me a lot in understanding the overall flow.